# Empty space under the footer

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot of options, but was unable to to find a solution.

[Here is a page with a problem](http://bogz.us/shop_main/#filter=.Antique-Wallets).

When selected All products, everything ok.

When we choose a specific category (eg. Antique Wallets), footer jumps and there is a blank space under it.
I can not even understand what element has such a great height (it's not body, html).

Help me, please!

Comment: Could you share your css file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this css

**CSS**

```
body{overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: @oshka if u got the solution, u can approve the answer by the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

Change the height attribute in footer (css):

```
#footer {
  background: url("http://bogz.us/wp-content/themes/studio/images/bg/bg_img_bottom_06.png") bottom center no-repeat!important;
  height: 1203px;
}
```